# Actualize a Angular 15 y ya no puedo hacer la inyeccion de dependencias

Tags: angular, component, inyeccion-de-dependencias, componentes, angular15

Recientemente migre mi versión de angular 7 a la 15, después hacer la actualización he obtenido la siguiente excepción en mi inyección de dependencias:

```
Error: src/app/dashboard/transactions/list-transactions/list-transactions.component.html:35:25 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'control' since it isn't a known property of 'app-validate'.
1. If 'app-validate' is an Angular component and it has 'control' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-validate' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.  
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Esta es una captura desde donde realizo la inyección

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo fuente del componente que recibe la inyección.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, UntypedFormControl } from '@angular/forms';
// Service
import { ValidateService } from './validate.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'admin-gulf-validate',
  templateUrl: './validate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./validate.component.scss']
})
export class ValidateComponent implements OnInit {

  message: string;

  @Input() public control: UntypedFormControl;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  get errorMessage() {
    for (let propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
        this.message = ValidateService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
        return this.message;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: el componente que muestras tiene `selector: 'admin-gulf-validate',` pero en la imagen del html tienes `app-validate`. A mi entender estas mostrando dos componentes diferentes, una de dos, en tu html deberías tener `<admin-gulf-validate [control]=".....`, o bien, el typescript que nos estas mostrando no es el que corresponde

Comment: Ya homologue los nommbres de componentes, pero el error persiste

Comment: Te dejo [este enlace](https://update.angular.io/?v=7.0-15.0) para que le des una revisada ya que para realizar la migración debes primero realizar algunos cambios en el código no solo actualizar las versiones.

Comment: Asegurarte que tegas ValidateComponent importado en el modulo donde lo estas llamando. No publicas el modulo, sería bueno que lo hicieras. Otra problema que veo es que al usar el nombre `control` puedes tener algún problema con los modulos `ReactiveFormsModule`, que genera una directiva de nombre `control`. Yo cambiaría ese nombre por algo como `@Input('control_mio')` y desde fuera lo llamaría `[control_mio]`.

Comment: Por cierto, migraste de versión en versión? De la 7 a la 15 está la 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14. Fuiste migrando tu código de una en una? Entre la v7 y v8 hay mucha diferencia.

Comment: https://update.angular.io/?v=7.0-8.0